# How can I locate all subversion repositories on my system?

Tags: directory, subversion

I can use this command  `locate --regex '/.git$' | grep username` to locate all git repositories on my system, but because the `.svn` appears in subdirectories of repositories the command `locate --regex '/.svn$' | grep username` work as well.

The former produced about 120 and the latter over 14,000.

What file or directory name should I search for to lcate subverson repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Git, every working copy is its own repository. This is not the case for SVN. So if you actually want to find *repositories*, and they are in the default location and on the local machine, this suffices:

```
ls /var/svn
```

Assuming you actually want to find *working copies*, SVN since version 1.7 only places `.svn` files at the top level of a working copy, so the command

```
find / -type d -name '.svn'
```

would work just fine.  Alternatively, if you've used earlier SVN and do have these directories littered throughout, you may try:

```
find / -type d -name '.svn' -exec dirname {} \; \
| sort \
| awk 'NR == 1 || $0 !~ "^"LAST { LAST = $0; print}'
```

This lists all directories containing `.svn` subdirectories, then prints only those that do not contain another as a prefix.

---

I've found a computer containing `locate`, where

```
$ locate --version
mlocate 0.26
Copyright (C) 2007 Red Hat, Inc. All rights reserved.
This software is distributed under the GPL v.2.

This program is provided with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

On this system, an approach similar to the final `find` example:

```
locate -r '/\.svn$' \
| sed 's/^\(.*\)$/"\1"/' \
| xargs dirname \
| sort \
| awk 'NR == 1 || $0 !~ "^"LAST { LAST = $0; print }'
```

Comment: I wanted to use the `locate` database to speed it up. I have that find command lurking somewhere in my snippets database. Can you cookup a regex that will match only on a single instance of the string `.svn`? Regexes are not my forte :)

Comment: @vfclists Untested: `\([^.]\|\.[^s]\|\.s[^v]\|\.sv[^n]\)*\.svn\([^.]\|\.[^s]\|\.s[^v]\|\.sv[^n]\)*`

Comment: @vfclists Or replace the second `\(…\)` block with `$`, since `.svn` is never a subdirectory of another `.svn`. As far as I can see, you'll still need the `dirname` and filter, though. (By the way, you probably want to anchor that regex anyway, with `^…$`)

Comment: @vfclists I found a machine with `locate`, and added a method that uses that instead of `find`